# Conda: New python 3.7 environment created, but Spyder opened a python 3.5 environment instead

Tags: python, windows, selenium, conda, spyder

```
conda
conda create --name py37 python=3.7

activate py37
spyder
```

Those were the commands I had entered. But Spyder opened a 3.5.4 python instead which was the base environment's python version.

Some context:

I was trying to install selenium earlier but I could not import the module within python. So I installed a previous conda revision, and tried installing selenium again. Still, selenium could not be imported. Then I realized Spyder wasn't opening right. I believe it was working fine before this. When it changed, the Spyder IDE layout when I opened Spyder was changed.

What could be the problem? Do I need to reinstall conda?

Comment: How does the question relates to _Selenium_?

Comment: Did you install Spyder in your py37 env?